# Dropbox - How to retrieve the content of a folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropbox

I want to get a JSON that describes the content of the folder. [Dropbox API Metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) says I only need the following link address and the path to my public folder

a) LINK to Metadata + path to my folder

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/<path>
```

b) Path to my folder

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2w...........73z4na?dl=0
```

if I cobined a) and b) in the browserbar I always get an ERROR:

```
{"error": "No auth method found."}
```

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The [/metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) Dropbox API endpoint takes `path` parameter, which should be the relative path to the desired file or folder inside a user's Dropbox account. For example, this may look like "/Documents/Resume.docx". Your sample is a shared link though, which doesn't contain the necessary path.

In addition, the [/metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) Dropbox API endpoint is part of the Dropbox Core API, which requires the user to first authorize a Dropbox API app to access their account. As you don't have that part done, you get that auth error.

You should work through the instructions and tutorial for whatever SDK or library you're trying to use, if any. There's also an OAuth guide for the Dropbox API that should be helpful:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide